# Pandas append row using a dictionary somehow adds columns for some of the new dictionary items

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a very basic csv file, NewProjectProxy.csv, containing data for a dataframe.

Its contents are 3 rows x 12 columns, with column headings as follows:

```
    EL_No  Type  EL_Name  Room_Name  Wall_Height Wall_Length Part Material Finish Width Height Depth
0  100000  Room      NaN     Room_1  96           60         NaN     NaN    NaN    NaN  NaN    NaN
1  101000  Wall   Wall_1        NaN  NaN          NaN        NaN     NaN    NaN    NaN  NaN    NaN
2  101001  Part      NaN        NaN  NaN          NaN        BEP     NaN    NaN    0.75  30.25  24.625
```

My code is:

```
import pandas as pd
newProjectData = pd.read_csv("C:/myPy38/CabinetProjectData/NewProject/NewProjectProxy.csv")
new_row = {'EL_No':200000,'Type':'Room','Room_Name':'Kitchen','Wall_Height':96,'Wall_Length':84}
#append row to the dataframe
updated = newProjectData.append(new_row, ignore_index=True)
print(updated)
```

When I run it I get no error messages but I get a partially correct ouput.

The result is 4 rows x 15 columns where the original is 3 rows x 12 columns. I'm adding new data using some of the headings in the csv file as keys for new values in my dictionary, and I'm expecting 4 rows  x 12 columns with some NaN results in cells where I did not add a value.

```
    EL_No  Type  EL_Name  Room_Name  ...   Depth  Room_Name Wall_Height  Wall_Length
0  100000  Room      NaN     Room_1  ...     NaN        NaN         NaN          NaN
1  101000  Wall   Wall_1        NaN  ...     NaN        NaN         NaN          NaN
2  101001  Part      NaN        NaN  ...  24.625        NaN         NaN          NaN
3  200000  Room      NaN        NaN  ...     NaN    Kitchen        96.0         84.0
```

The append row result is correct for the first 2 items in the dictionary, placing the data in the correct columns.

What I can't work out is why this code adds 3 new columns to the end, with the same names as the columns in my original csv file for the last 3 items in my dictionary. I have checked the spelling of the dictionary keys to be sure they are the same as the ones in the csv file.

Could there be a problem with which character set is used? How might I resolve that?

Comment: Can you upload the csv?While saving in excel often empty columns are included in csv.If you open csv in a code editor , you must be able to see extra commas.

Comment: ``newProjectData.columns = newProjectData.columns.str.strip()``, then perform ``updated = newProjectData.append..`` might be spaces column header

Comment: here is a quick way to see if the keys in the new dictionary are consistent with the data frame's columns: `assert set(new_row.keys()) - set(df.columns) == set()`

Comment: The comments were similar and pointed me to a solution. There were leading spaces in column names in the csv file - I found them using a text editor. So the line of code supplied by susanth worked, and so did removing the leading spaces in the csv file headings.

Comment: jsmart offers an interesting idea but I didn't know how to place the suggested line of code in my code, so I didn't try it. What is the expected result of running this line of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue does not replicate with sample you have provided.   I suspect your dictionary keys are marginally incorrect resulting in new columns.  Have added a list comprehension `t` to check for this.

```
newProjectData = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""    EL_No  Type  EL_Name  Room_Name  Wall_Height Wall_Length Part Material Finish Width Height Depth
0  100000  Room      NaN     Room_1  96           60         NaN     NaN    NaN    NaN  NaN    NaN
1  101000  Wall   Wall_1        NaN  NaN          NaN        NaN     NaN    NaN    NaN  NaN    NaN
2  101001  Part      NaN        NaN  NaN          NaN        BEP     NaN    NaN    0.75  30.25  24.625"""), sep="\s+")

new_row = {'EL_No':200000,'Type':'Room','Room_Name':'Kitchen','Wall_Height':96,'Wall_Length':84}
print(newProjectData.columns)
t = [f"ok: {k}" if k in newProjectData else k for k in new_row.keys() if k ]
print(t)
updated = newProjectData.append(new_row, ignore_index=True)
print(updated.columns)
```

**output**

```
Index(['EL_No', 'Type', 'EL_Name', 'Room_Name', 'Wall_Height', 'Wall_Length',
       'Part', 'Material', 'Finish', 'Width', 'Height', 'Depth'],
      dtype='object')
['ok: EL_No', 'ok: Type', 'ok: Room_Name', 'ok: Wall_Height', 'ok: Wall_Length']
Index(['EL_No', 'Type', 'EL_Name', 'Room_Name', 'Wall_Height', 'Wall_Length',
       'Part', 'Material', 'Finish', 'Width', 'Height', 'Depth'],
      dtype='object')
```

Comment: Your suspicion was correct, see my comment to responses above.

Comment: My check mark applies to you as well as the responders above, who only provided comments, not an answer as defined in stackoverflow.